# HTTP client library in Groovy

Tags: http, groovy

I am interested in querying a REST API using Groovy. I found HttpURLClient which seems like it should do what I want, but Groovy Console complains "unable to resolve class HttpURLClient"
I found this link that has sample code for HttpURLClient: http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/httpurlclient.html

But copy-pasting that code gives the same error.

I also looked into using HTTPBuilder which also seems like it might work, but that gave similar errors as well.

Any idea what I need to do to get these to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you installed the library?

http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/download.html

**edit**

If you want to use the SNAPSHOT release, you can add the resolver in as an annotation, rather than editing the xml file;

```
@GrabResolver( name='codehaus.snapshot', root='http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org', m2compatible='true' )
@Grab( 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.2-SNAPSHOT' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
```

At the top of your script should do it

Comment: Hmm, I guess not. The @Grab annotation didn't work. So I followed these directions http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/download.html (under Grape) to download it, but it failed:


`grape resolve org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.5.2-SNAPSHOT
Error in resolve:
 Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.5.2-SNAPSHOT: not found]
Perhaps the grape is not installed?`

Comment: Okay, I got it working, I had to add the 'snapshots' repository to the ~/.groovy/groovyConfig.xml file. Thanks!

Comment: @mindthief You can add the snapshot repo using `@GrabResolver` and avoid having to edit the `groovyConfig.xml` file

Comment: Do you know how I can avoid using the runtime "Grabbing" altogether? I want to install it on my system so that I can just import it and have it work, without the @Grab annotation. I tried installing on the command line but, while that succeeded, I still need to have @Grab in the code...

Comment: Download the jar and all its dependencies, then put them all on the classpath as you would with Java

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know how I can avoid using the
>   runtime "Grabbing" altogether? I want
>   to install it on my system so that I
>   can just import it and have it work,
>   without the @Grab annotation. I tried
>   installing on the command line but,
>   while that succeeded, I still need to
>   have

Hi,

check your user home for:

```
ls .groovy/grapes/
```

There you should find the jars you installed with Grape before.

Probably Groovy does not know yet, where it can find these grapes. Therefore you have to add the Grape path to your **Groovy Classloading Configuration** which can be found in the place, where you installed Groovy:

> ${groovy.home}/conf/groovy-starter.conf

Add this line at the end for loading Grapes:

```
# load grape libraries
load !{user.home}/.groovy/grapes/**/*.jar
```

Be aware that you might have to remove either **xml-apis** or **xerces** from your Grapes in order for the HttpClient to function correctly. (This might be just a problem using Grails and the HttpClient)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command line in the $GROOVY_HOME/bin folder

grape resolve org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.6

sudo grape install org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.6